how to get struct fieldname and related comment in rust
#[derive(SomeMarco)]
struct MyStruct {
    field1: i32,    // this is a comment 
    field2: String, // hello world
}

I now have a struct like this, and i want to get the field name and comment, how to achieve this goal
(i'm new in rust, in other language like java we can use reflection, but it seems that rust don't support reflection)
get struct fieldname and related comment

As you say, Rust doesn't have reflection.  Maybe a procedural macro or build script could help you here, but chances are there's a more idiomatic way to solve your underlying problem.  Why do you want to do this?

@eggyal i want to export multiple huge struct(with hundreds of field) into multiple json file

Can you elaborate further?  If you're just looking to de/serialise instances of your Rust data structures from/to JSON then perhaps you're after something like serde_json?  If you want your struct definitions to be synchronised with a JSON schema then perhaps you're after something like schemars?

@eggyal i used serde_json, but it can't get field name and related comment.
Actually, I was asked to generate a document(for the struct), for non-programmers to see.
I feel like I should use Rust's #![doc()] to solve this problem, but I'm not sure if there is a better way.

Why would non-programmers ever be concerned with the data structures used within your code?

Maybe rustdoc is what you want?

rustdoc should be able to help me, thanks guys

IDK if Rig might be any help here, but it simplifies Rust apps with LLM integrations, so could be worth checking out rig rs etc. if you're deep into Rust dev projects.
Ever worked with LLMs in Rust before?

no,but thanks for answer,i will I'll go take a look at Rig.
